# Why does "gradle build" every time I open Android Studio

Tags: android-gradle-plugin

I'm somewhat new to Android development. I've noticed that every time I open Android Studio (which then attempts to re-open my most recent project) I see "gradle build" star running.

In my mind, if gradle is similar to "make" it should only be building when something has changed or I force the project to rebuild.

So why is it running just by opening the project?  The sluggishness of Android Studio and gradle are two big turn-offs for me overall, as a new Android developer..

Thanks
Michael

Comment: My project is 'happy' when I close Android Studio, and when I open the application, it doesn't build until after I manually run gradle build.  It never used to do that.